# Common mode inductance of a three-phase reactor

Tags: ac

I have designed a three-phase differential mode reactor on a 5-legged core.  I am trying to calculate the common mode inductance of this reactor.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you link to the generic design?

Comment: I am not sure how to attach my design here.

Comment: Use the picture logo symbol when editing your question to embed a png or jpeg image.

Answer (score 1):

Differential VS common mode reactor: it matters how do you draw currents, since it is a three phase, then all currents you draw have the same direction, in turn this is a common mode choke as you would correctly find in the literature, catalogues, shop items,...
AFIK a choke, differential or common mode is not possible to build with 5 limb core. The extra limbs give a free path, even for sum of fluxes that would cancel out.